# is this sentence correct? "actually one of the secrets of getting rich is about finding a way to make passive income"

Tags: grammar

I'm beginner English learner. I was talking to someone about online jobs, then I said this sentence but I'm not sure if it makes sense. or is that correct grammatically?
But I think he got it.

**"actually one of the secrets of getting rich is about finding a way to make passive income"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only questionable thing about the sentence is the word "about". It makes sense without that word. With "about", which seems to modify "one of the secrets", we have "one of the secrets ... is about ...", and while we can certainly say that a secret is about something, the something is different from the secret itself.

If the secret is "investing in the right stock", we could say it is "about" finding a way to make passive income. But "to make passive income" sounds to me like the secret itself, not the general topic of the secret.